# for loop with in the jsrender template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsrender

In my working scenario i am using the following code snippet with in the js render template:

```
{{:#data['" + columnName + "']}}
```

and this will return the value as:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

How to get a specific property from this array object `[object Object],[object Object]` within the js render template using a for loop?

Comment: Can you provide a simplified version of your code (perhaps a jsFiddle) that we can use to see a bit more of what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `{{for}}` to iterate over an array. Something like this:

```
<ul>
{{for columnName}}
  <li>{{:Property}}</li>
{{/for}}
</ul>
```

Inside the loop, your base scope automatically becomes that particular object in the array, so you can output any of the object's properties directly with `{{:Property}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I have given example to demonstrate how jsrender for loop and props working.
StudentList has array of student details and to iterate loop on Student list
you have to just use `{{for StudentList}}{{/for}}`.

Now each student have three property, so iterate through property you can use `{{props}}{{/props}}` tag and to render data use `{{>key}}` and `{{>prop}}`

Doc: https://www.jsviews.com/#propstag

**JSON data:**

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->

"StudentList": [
        {
            "RollNo": 1,
            "Name": "John Doe",
            "Subject": "Maths"            
        },
        {
            "RollNo": 2,
            "Name": "Jane Doe",
            "Subject": "Physics"            
        },
        ...
```

**Render Template:**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

{{for StudentList}}
    <tr>
        {{props #data}}
            <td>{{>key}}</td><td>{{>prop}}</td>
        {{/props}}
    </tr>
{{/for}}
```

Comment: It would be good if you explain a bit more what you did, to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

***For iterating over an array***, see http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag. (Lower in the page shows the use of the tag for looping over an array).

Also, some comments about your template example:

It looks like you are using a generated template, with the value of the `columnName` parameter inserted. So if `columnName` has the value `"fooColumn"` your template snippet is `{{:#data['fooColumn']}}` - which is actually equivalent to `{{:#data.fooColumn}}`, which can be further simplified to `{{:fooColumn}}`.

(I assume the value of `columnName` is a valid JavasScript name - not some value like `"foo column"`, say, with white space - in which case your syntax would indeed be appropriate.)

Now, if `#data.fooColumn` is an array of objects each of which has a `'itemProperty'` property, then using `{{for}}` to iterate over the array looks like this (slight change on David Ward's example):

```
<ul>
  {{for fooColumn}}
    <li>{{:itemProperty}}</li>
  {{/for}}
</ul>
```

The generated form of that using columnName would be

```
"<ul>{{for " + columnName + "}}<li>{{:itemProperty}}</li>{{/for}}</ul>"
```